# How do you sync a ListView and List model using MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I am attempting to use the MVVM pattern to display a List of objects that can be updated in the UI.  I would also like some basic operations like Add/Remove.  Right now I have a simple `Customer` model that is just a first and last name.  I have the `DataContext` assigned to the `ViewModel`.  In the `ViewModel` class I have the “model” (which is just a `List` of Customers) that will be injected at a later point.   To keep the underlying `List` model up to date, I wrap the `List` with an `ObservableCollection` each time it’s accessed.  In doing this, it doesn’t seem to keep the `SelectedValue` active because when you remove the `SelectedValue`, it sets it to `null` and clears out the selection in the `ListView`.  This means that I would need some manual tracking (which I am hoping to avoid).
I have tried to keep an `ObservableCollection` as a member variable to the `ViewModel` class, but this only copies the underlying list of data and doesn’t keep it synced if you add/remove objects from it.

I also want to avoid using `ObservableCollection` as the model, since this seems more geared toward `ViewModel` data binding support ([reference; see Using it in the model](http://updatecontrols.net/doc/tips/common_mistakes_observablecollection)).
Has anyone done this before and found a good way to keep the `List` model in sync but also data bind to the `ListView` using `ObservableCollection`?

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="TestCollectionAndSelectedItem.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestCollectionAndSelectedItem"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:IndexConverter x:Key="IndexConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="35*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="276*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding Path=AddCustomer}"  Width="95" Margin="22,11,0,231" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <Label Content="First" Height="26" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="263,95,0,155" Grid.Row="1" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedCustomer.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="31" Width="133" IsEnabled="True" Margin="345,93,25,152" Name="textBox1" Grid.Row="1" />
        <Label Content="Last" Height="26" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="263,139,0,111" Grid.Row="1" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedCustomer.LastName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="133" Height="31" IsEnabled="True" Margin="345,137,25,108" Name="textBox2" Grid.Row="1" />
        <ListView SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCustomer, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="listviewNames" Margin="22,56,258,77" Grid.Row="1">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Number"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                            AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, 
                            Converter={StaticResource IndexConverter}}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Last" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastName}" Width="80"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="First" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" Width="80"/>
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Button Command="{Binding Path=RemoveCustomer}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=listviewNames, Path=SelectedIndex}" Content="Remove" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,11,0,231" Width="95" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   // wont go here, just example
   List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>() { 
      new Customer() { LastName = "Anderson", FirstName = "John" },
      new Customer() { LastName = "NoName", FirstName = "" } };

   public MainWindow()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      DataContext = new ViewModel(customers);
   }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   private List<Customer> _customersModel; 
   private Customer _selectedCustomer;

   public DelegateCommand<object> AddCustomer { get; private set; }
   public DelegateCommand<int> RemoveCustomer { get; private set; }

   public ViewModel(List<Customer> listOfCustomers)
   {
      _customersModel = listOfCustomers;
      AddCustomer = new DelegateCommand<object>((a) => Add(), (a) => CanAdd());
      RemoveCustomer = 
         new DelegateCommand<int>((a) => Remove(a), (a) => CanRemove());
   }

   public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers
   {
      get
      {
         return new ObservableCollection<Customer>(_customersModel);
      }
      set
      {
         _customersModel = new List<Customer>(value);
         OnPropertyChanged("Customers");
      }
   }

   public Customer SelectedCustomer
   {
      get { return _selectedCustomer; }
      set
      {
         if (_selectedCustomer != value)
         {
            _selectedCustomer = value;
            UpdateCommands();
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCustomer");
         }
      }
   }

   public void Add()
   {
      _customersModel.Add(new Customer() { FirstName = "", LastName = "" });
      UpdateCommands();
      OnPropertyChanged("Customers");
   }

   public Boolean CanAdd()
   {
      return _customersModel.Count < 8;
   }

   public void Remove(int selectedIndex)
   {
      _customersModel.Remove(_selectedCustomer);
      UpdateCommands();
      OnPropertyChanged("Customers");
   }

   public Boolean CanRemove()
   {
      return (_selectedCustomer != null) && 
             (_customersModel != null) &&
             (_customersModel.Count > 0);
   }

   public void UpdateCommands()
   {
      RemoveCustomer.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
      AddCustomer.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
   }

   protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
   {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
      {
         handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
      }
   } 
}
```

**IndexConverter.cs**

```
public class IndexConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type TargetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)value;
      ListView listView = 
         ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item) as ListView;
      int index = 
         listView.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item) + 1;
      return index.ToString();
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, 
      Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

**Customer.cs**

```
public class Customer
{
   public String FirstName { get; set; }
   public String LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend exposing your domain model directly on your view models. If you're able to, it's probably a sign that you have an [anemic domain model](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html). This is very popular, but it doesn't necessarily mean it's correct.

You could expose an `ObservableCollection` of a `CustomerViewModel`. The `CustomerViewModel` would be a DTO for the purposes of binding to your view (as well as having properties that may augment the underlying model).

The point at which you need to run appropriate domain logic to reflect the actions of the user will depend on your UI. For example, the user may make all the changes to list and signify all of the changes at once, or you may need to run domain logic on every list change. Either way, this should be driven by your domain, and then the UI updated to reflect those changes depending on success or failure within the domain.

So it's likely that when the view model is activated, you wish to retrieve all of the customers from a data store either via an injected application service, or directly through a repository. These customers would then be mapped to your DTO (`CustomerViewModel`) and presented to the user. Then, when a save option is selected in your UI, the verb that sits on your view model would map those DTOs back to your domain objects, and you would persist those changes via the application service or repository.

Comment: Thanks devdigital, I don't directly expose my domain model, its wrapped in an `ObservableCollection` as you mentioned: `public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers`.  The idea would be that changes are commited to the model immediately and not at some other point (thats just the design decision).

Comment: That's still exposing the domain model - instead, have an ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel>. When the user adds a customer to the collection (or removes etc) then invoke your domain logic (via application service or repository), then on success, update the observable collection to reflect the change.

Comment: Hmm, how would the List of Customers tie into this, would the List be in the CustomerViewModel, or is the CustomerViewModel representing one customer.  Do you have a code example?

Comment: CustomerViewModel represents one Customer. You don't need to maintain a List<Customer>. On activation, you build your ObservableCollection<CustomerViewModel> from the collection returned by your service/repository. The view model binds to this observable collection, and in your AddCustomer verb on your view model, you run your domain logic (for example in order to persist the change immediately), check the result, and then update your observable collection to reflect the change.